# How to change class when Active img source will change in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```html
<img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" ">
<div class="game-star" style="height: 198px; overflow: hidden;">
    <ul>
        <li class="Active">
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" ">
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Millions<br>RMB 1000.00</h3>

            <!-- <p>RMB 625.78</p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah<br>RMB 3,266.41</h3>
            <!-- <p></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah Isis<br>RMB 4,982.78</h3>
            <!-- <p></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">发大财<br>RMB 8,888.88</h3>
            <!-- <p>RMB 396.42</p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">我发我发我发发发<br>RMB 9,999.99</h3>
            <!-- <p>RMB 28.89</p> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the image source when the `li` in `class` = "Active" while the class of "winner-nameMoolar" remain.

Only change particular of image source as below and the `class` remain.

Kindly advise

```
<img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" ">
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="game-star" style="height: 198px; overflow: hidden;">
    <ul>
        <li class="Active">
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" ">
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Millions<br>RMB 1000.00</h3>

            <!-- <p>RMB 625.78</p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah<br>RMB 3,266.41</h3>
            <!-- <p></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah Isis<br>RMB 4,982.78</h3>
            <!-- <p></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">发大财<br>RMB 8,888.88</h3>
            <!-- <p>RMB 396.42</p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
            <h3 class="winner-name">我发我发我发发发<br>RMB 9,999.99</h3>
            <!-- <p>RMB 28.89</p> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will help you..

```
if ( $('ul > li').hasClass('Active')){
        $('ul > li.Active').children('img').attr('src', 'here write path you want');
}
```

My check this code and work perfect for me.